# Passing keyword arguments to NumPy __array__ functions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In the past, a few questions have asked for help when getting the following exception:

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

These have usually been in the context of using another package, in which the `__array__` function has been defined without allowing for additional arguments. However, the underlying problem seems to be that it is impossible to allow for additional arguments even if you wanted to.

For example, defining the following class doesn't work:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> class MyArray:
        def __init__(self, arr):
            self.arr = arr
        def __array__(self, **kwargs):
            return np.array(self.arr, **kwargs)
>>> a=MyArray([1,2,3])
>>> np.array(a)
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.array(a, dtype=np.float32)
TypeError: MyArray.__array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Does anyone know why the usual mechanism for passing on keyword arguments doesn't seem to work for the `np.array`?

To add to the confusion, the following does work:

```
>>> class MyArray:
        def __init__(self, arr):
            self.arr = arr
        def __array__(self, dtype=None):
            return np.array(self.arr, dtype)
        
>>> a=MyArray([1,2,3])
>>> np.array(a, dtype=np.float32)
array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

It looks as if I could add all the remaining keyword arguments that `np.array` accepts, but that doesn't seem very Pythonic.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The traditional way to solve this is by using `(self, *args, **kwargs)`, so you catch both positional and keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to solve this is by using (self, *args, **kwargs), so you catch both positional and keyword arguments.

This works:

```
import numpy as np
class MyArray:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
    def __array__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.array(self.arr, *args, **kwargs)
a=MyArray([1,2,3])
print(np.array(a))
print(np.array(a, dtype=np.float32))
```

Comment: Many thanks. You're quite right. That does seem to fix it, but I know of plenty of examples where **kwargs is used on its own, i.e., when arbitrary positional arguments are not allowed. I suppose that NumPy must have some internal argument handler that requires both or none.

Comment: Yes.  That's the key point -- if you don't know the requirements with 100% certainty, then you must use both.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you can use `*args`/`**kwargs`. They are useful because they are opaque, but they are also unhelpfully brief. Given that there is only one positional argument, I would go ahead and name it:

```py
import numpy as np
class MyArray:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
    def __array__(self, dtype, **kwargs):
        return np.array(self.arr, dtype, **kwargs)
```

It's not many characters more, and it's clearer what you're passing through in case you (or a contributor) want to modify this method in the future.

---

Edit: Removed `=None` from dtype argument. As Ray Osborn noted, numpy will always pass dtype as a positional argument.

Comment: But the NumPy documentation gives dtype as a keyword argument with a default value of None. Your example suggests that it is being treated as an optional positional parameter, which would mean that the NumPy documentation is wrong.

Comment: Not at all.  If I say `def x(abc=1, def=2):`, I can call that with two positional parameters.  Just because there is a default does not FORCE it to be a keyword argument.  That determination is made more by the caller than the callee.

Comment: I have long known that you can enter keyword arguments without the keys, although I think it's odd that Python allows it. However, it is perfectly possible to write a function that will accept **kwargs without *args, so I think it's a regrettable peculiarity of the NumPy argument handling. For example, see https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/5572 for an example of a PR in a major package, which solved the issue with a bit of a hack presumably because they didn't know about the trick of adding *args.

Comment: > But the NumPy documentation gives dtype as a keyword argument with a default value of None.
This is a good point, `ndarray(obj)` always calls `obj.__array__(dtype)`. Edited my post above.